# How to group by rows when one column has the same value

Tags: r

I have ended up with a dataframe called total that looks like this:

```
Rpt         Col1    Col2   Col3
Jim          5        0      4
Jim          0        8      8
Charlie      6        7      4
Jim          6        2      4
Charlie      5        5      0
```

I would like to merge the rows with the same name in the Rpt column so that it looks like:

```
  Rpt         Col1    Col2   Col3
  Jim          11      10     16
  Charlie      11      12      4
```

I tried using dplyr but I probably dont really understand the syntax properly so I tried

```
library(dplyr)
total2<- total %>% count(Rpt)
```

but it gives me a single count column which doesnt really seem to count anything I want

Comment: While the solution is mentioned in that answer, I think SO community would benefit by having a similar question with different wording to help "lure in" visitors from outer google/space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
aggregate(. ~ Rpt, data = df, FUN = sum)
      Rpt Col1 Col2 Col3
1 Charlie   11   12    4
2     Jim   11   10   16
```

Comment: Definitely the simplest. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

With dplyr you can use `summarise_each` to compute the sum per Rpt in each column:

```
library(dplyr)
total %>% 
  group_by(Rpt) %>%
  summarise_each(funs(sum))
```

Or using data.table (slightly different approach than that by Pgibas):

```
library(data.table)
setDT(total)[, lapply(.SD, sum), by = Rpt]
```

Note that dplyr's `count` function is used to count the number of rows per group in a data frame.

Answer (score 3):

Example using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)

total <- data.table(total)
total[, list(sum(Col1),sum(Col2),sum(Col3)), by=list(Rpt)]
```

Comment: `setDT(total)[, .(sum(Col1),sum(Col2),sum(Col3)), by=Rpt]` is shorter